# Eclipse - find all classes that extend interface

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

We have an interface that has a child interface.  Ie:

```
public interface GenCalculator extends Serializable {}

public interface SpecialCalculator extends GenCalculator {}
```

In Eclipse, how can you find all interface-s that extend in this case `GenCalculator`?

If I right click, select "Open Type Hierarchy" in the `GenCalculator` interface, I only see classes that implement that `GenCalculator` interface. I want to see everything - those that implement and those that extend.

We're on Eclipse v.3.2.2.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to view all descendants

Press it the combination a second time (see fine print in initial popup) if you want to display super interfaces/classes.

Comment: This doesn't appear to tell me the interfaces that *extend* GenCalculator.

Comment: If you put cursor on GenCalculator and hit Ctrl-T, it works for me in 3.2.2. I mocked up an example that uses interfaces (versus classes).

Comment: For reference, the Mac OS X shortcut is: Cmd + T

Comment: Pressing `F4` also gives the Type Hierarchy. :)

Answer (score 7):

You CAN do this, but it doesn't involve the Type Hierarchy.

In the Eclipse editor pane, highlight the name of the class of which you want to find extending classes.

Then go to Search > Java Search and the name of that class should be prepoplated in the search field.

Check the 'Limit To > Implementors' radio button.

Click the Search button.

Comment: That's right. This is the answer to the question. What is wanted are the classes that implement it.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> brings up the search, go to Java search, and click "All Occurrences".

Comment: It works.  Also returns references to variables of type "GenCalculator" which I don't want (in this case).  Would be nice to have easy right click option.  Would have thought that would there.

Answer (score 4):

Click on `GenCalculator` in the editor and press `CTRL+T`. You will see the quick complete hierarchy.

It is possible to have that aswell in the "Open Type Hierarchy" view, but you will have to switch the different options (button in the upper right corner).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [nWire for Java](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-java). However, nWire requires Eclipse 3.3 and above. I highly recommend upgrading.

Comment: Oh come'on now! Upgrading and all is too much time consuming for his tiny little problem, he just needs one simple shortcut!!

Answer (score 0):

Move your mouse on the class name and press CTRL+T

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse：
F4：Open Type Hierarchy --（the new open windows）-》 show the Supertype Hierarchy（can show the interface）
[image]

Answer (score -8):

**You can't do it in only one search.**

May be you could use the "Text Search" option and wildcards, something like searching for "*s YourInterfaceName" (trying to catch "extend**s** YourInterfaceName" and "implement**s** YourInterfaceName") but is too tricky.

Comment: From what I can tell this is correct.  Surprising.  So the correct answer is no answer I guess..

Comment: Using Ctrl-T gives you the hierarchy. You don't need to "Text Search" it.

Comment: The answer by "Michael Easter" is obviously working just fine. Please update the chosen answer Marcus. thx

Comment: Today I tried Michael Easter answer and works fine. I voted it... I think it was an improvement in Eclipse. I can't delete my answer because is the accepted one :(