# Search by Implementation class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, search

Can one search by the implementation or its methods in eclipse? It would be really useful.
An example is given below.

```
public interface Foo {
    public void method();
}

public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    // I should be able to select this and search and it should 
    // show the whoever called Foo.method
    public void method() {

    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add an example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you see a method, called from interface, then just position mouse cursor over it, press ctrl and you see menu with options "Open Declaration | Open Implementation". In your case press "Open Implementation".
In case this method is implemented by many classes you will get a popup with "Types implementing or defining...". Quite nice feature :)

**UPDATE**: according to your example... If I understood it right, then when you select method, press ctrl+shift+G and you see all places where this method is called.

Comment: I also use Ctrl+Alt+H (call hierarchy) as it allows to explore deeper how a method is used by chains of calls.

Comment: This feature is called Hyperlinking.

Answer (score 6):

Select "Foo" in the editor -> right-click -> **Open Type Hierarchy** (or **F4**). The "Type Hierarchy" View will open -> On this View, click the icon for the function "**Show the Sub-Type Hierarchy**" (or "**Show All Inherited Members**").

Eclipse will show all the Child classes.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573634/311525). Instead of using **CTRL+H** or **CTRL+SHIFT+G** you can use **CTRL+T** to open a pop-up in place instead of a new Eclipse tab as the other methods do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default search option. Access it by pressing **CTRL+H.** Go to **Java search** tab. Here you can write method name and search for it.